# Equivalent to command which can be used in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, postman

I've this command

```
curl -X POST -u admin:116c197495ef372f129b85a8a2ca4aadc2 localhost:8080/job/test/build
```

I need a equivalent command which I can use in postman to trigger action.

P.s: I'm new to this & using nodeJs for backend

Comment: You can just paste the cURL into postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Postman app or the Web version, use the Import feature to covert that curl syntax to a Postman request.

Go to `Import > Raw text` and paste your curl command.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#importing-data-into-postman